# surjectivity of double dual map for weil divisors on normal varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

If $X$ is a normal complex variety, and $D$ is an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-Cartier Weil divisor, then there is a natural map $\mathcal{O}(D) \otimes \mathcal{O}(-D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X$.  My question: under what conditions is this map surjective?  Obviously this is true if $X$ is smooth or $D$ is Cartier; I am interested in the singular, non-Cartier case.  I am happy to assume $X$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-factorial and log terminal, if that helps at all.

Here is what I know:

1. It is not surjective in general.  For instance, if $D$ is a ruling of the quadric cone, then this map is not surjective.

**EDIT: Statement 2 is not correct:**
*I had convinced myself that the exact sequence below implies surjectivity, but this only holds if $\mathcal{O}_D(D)$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_D \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D)$, which is not true in general, hence statement 2 is false!*

2. If $X$ is log terminal, and $D$ is Cartier in codimension 2 (meaning the non-Cartier locus of $D$ has codimension at least 3 in $X$), this map is surjective.  This follows because the sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_X(D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D(D) \to 0$ is exact in this case.

Are there any other conditions that guarantee surjectivity of this map?  I am particularly interested in the case when $D$ happens to be the (reduced, but possibly not irreducible) exceptional locus of a birational morphism $f: X \rightarrow Y$.

**EDIT: in the comments below, it appears that this only holds if $D$ is, in fact, a Cartier divisor.**

Comment: It would help if you clarify your definitions.  I assume that you are defining $\mathcal{O}(-D)$ to be the pushforward from the regular locus of $X$ of the invertible ideal sheaf of $D$ (considered as a closed subscheme).  Is $\mathcal{O}(D)$ defined to be the pushforward from the regular locus of the dual invertible sheaf?

Comment: Are you sure that 2 is correct?  Let $M$ be a Fano manifold of dimension $\geq 2$ such that $\omega_M \cong \mathcal{O}(-r \underline{E})$ for some effective Cartier divisor $\underline{E}$ and for an integer $r>1$, e.g., this holds for $M\cong \mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$.  Let $X$ be Spec of the section ring of $M$ with respect to the invertible sheaf $\omega_M^\vee \cong \mathcal{O}(r\underline{E})$.  It seems to me that $X$ is even canonical.  Let $D$ be the divisor of $E$.  I do not believe that the pairing is surjective in this case . . .

Comment: Regarding 2, you do have such a short exact sequence.  However, $\mathcal{O}_X(D)\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_D$ is typically not an invertible sheaf on $D$.  I think this is the source of the trouble.

Comment: My instinct says that unless $D$ is Cartier, this map is not surjective. Does the following argument work? Suppose $\mathcal O_X(D)\otimes \mathcal O_X(-D)\to \mathcal O_X$ is surjective then working locally, let $\frak m$ the maximal ideal. Abusing notation, we have $1=\sum f_i g_i\in k=\mathcal O_X/\frak m$ for $f_i\in\mathcal O_X(D)$ and $g_i\in \mathcal O_X(-D)$ so $1=fg$ for $f\in\mathcal O_X(D)$, $g\in \mathcal O_X(-D)$. But then $0=(f)+(g)$ and $(f)+D\geq 0$, $(g)-D\geq 0$ imply $(f)=-D$ and $(g)=D$ so that $D$ is Cartier.

Comment: @JasonStarr I was using the definition that $\mathcal{O}_X(D)(U) = \{ f \in K(X) | (f)|_U + D|_U \ge 0 \}$ (coming from Karl Schwede's notes--definition 3.3 here: http://www.math.utah.edu/~smolkin/schwede_generalized_divisors.pdf ), but by reflexivity it should be the same as what you suggested.  I need to think a little more about your example first.

Comment: @Hacon -- thank you for your answer, although it seems to contradict what I was saying in (2)!  Here was my reasoning for (2): because $0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(-D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D \rightarrow 0$ is exact, after tensoring with $\mathcal{O}(D)$ we get $ \mathcal{O}(-D) \otimes \mathcal{O}(D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}(D) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_D(D) \rightarrow 0$, which should be exact on the left after modding out by torsion. Because the sequence in (2) is exact, this identifies $\mathcal{O}_X$ with that kernel. Am I missing something subtle?

Comment: @kdev.  You do have a short exact sequence as you write by Proposition 5.26, p. 163, of Koll'ar-Mori, "Birational Geometry of Algebraic Varieties".

Comment: @JasonStarr yes, thank you!  Do you see something wrong with the reasoning in my previous comment?

Comment: @kdev: I don't see why $\mathscr O_D\otimes\mathscr O_X(D)$ would be $\mathscr O_D(D)$. Restriction of a reflexive sheaf is not necessarily reflexive, so very likely you'd have to take the reflexive hull which screws up your short exact sequence.

Comment: I agree that there is a short exact sequence $0\to \mathcal O _X\to \mathcal O_X(D)\to \mathcal O_D(D)\to 0$ and $0\to (\mathcal O _X(-D)\otimes \mathcal O_X(D))/torsion \to \mathcal O_X(D)\to \mathcal O_D\otimes \mathcal O_X(D)\to 0$. I don't yet see how this contradicts what I said above: why is $(\mathcal O _X(-D)\otimes \mathcal O_X(D))/torsion \cong \mathcal O _X$ or equivalently $\mathcal O_D\otimes \mathcal O_X(D)\cong \mathcal O_D(D)$?

Comment: Here is why I think Christopher's argument works. Let $L$ be a reflexive sheaf of rank 1 and $\mathfrak m$ a maximal ideal. If $\dim L/\mathfrak m=1$, then  $L$ is Cartier by Nakayama. If you have another $L'$, then $(L\otimes L')/\mathfrak m$ surjects onto $(L/\mathfrak m)\otimes (L'/\mathfrak m)$, so if $L\otimes L'$ is a line bundle, then so are $L$ and $L'$.

Comment: Thank you!  I had mistakenly convinced myself that the notation $\mathcal{O}_D(D)$ simply meant $\mathcal{O}_D \otimes \mathcal{O}_X(D)$, but this is not the case!